# Booting with wrong drive letter. Cannot run regedit to fix

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, bitlocker, diskpart

My laptop is persisting in trying to boot from a recovery volume by labelling it `C:`, and won't boot to Windows in any mode. Stop code is `Inaccessible Boot Device`. On going into advanced recovery then command prompt I can see that a recovery volume is mounted as `C:` rather than the larger and normal system partition which holds Windows.

I've tried a number of things, including:

1. Reassigned label to correct partition in `diskpart` per [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/117336-enable-disable-automount-new-disks-drives-windows.html).
2. Turned off Automount and scrubbed Automount entries per the [same link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/117336-enable-disable-automount-new-disks-drives-windows.html)
3. Modifying (somewhat randomly) BIOS boot options re UEFI mode legacy etc.

The machine still wants to boot to the wrong volume.

If I look at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` with `reg query` (I cannot get to Windows to run `Regedit`) I can see that the mounts are mixed up. Because I cannot get to Windows to run RegEdit per [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/restore-system-boot-drive-letter). I'm uncertain what to do next.

Note that I am concerned about data loss. The drive is BitLocker encrypted.
I'm cautious not to delete the reg key from cmd prompt in-case I can't get it back.
I have little confidence in the recovery partition being up to date, and happy to disable it if I can re-enable.

### Background:

This happened when trying to fix my machine requesting Bitlocker recovery key on each reboot at the same time as doing a driver update. (silly to do the two things at once I know)
I have followed instructions to disable Bitlocker from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8ra7rv/bitlockered_pc_asks_for_recovery_key_every_time/). Only after re-enabling did I even get prompted for my recovery key, but at least I felt like I was getting somewhere since I can see the old C drive, but after remapping via `DISKPART` it comes back again per above.

Comment: By convention, `C:` is assigned during the boot process, to whichever drive is booting. Attempting to change the letter from outside that process is pretty pointless. You need to determine why it thinks it should boot from there rather than what letter it assigns the drive.

Comment: Yeah, fix your BCD, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. I believe it is trying to boot from Recovery either because it thinks it needs to in recovery mode, or because the Windows drive (which was `C:`, but is now `D:`) was temporarily unavailable as I messed with the Bitlocker.  How would I determine/confirm "why" it is reassigning the volume previously unassigned recovery partition and how would that help me/what are the next steps you recommend?

Comment: @TomYan do you mean fix BCD per [here](https://windowsreport.com/fix-corrupt-bcd-windows-10/#:~:text=If%20the%20BCD%20is%20missing,as%20grave%20as%20it%20looks)? if so, can this be run from same command line and will it leave my bitlocker contents intact and uncorrupted?

Comment: Fixing the BCD should not cause any change to your "C:" (unless it's in the same partition), but I'm not familiar with booting a bitlocker-locked drive so I don't know if you need special procedure. `bcdboot` is one of the ways to fix it, but I suggest you read the documentation of the program itself on Microsoft's website instead of some random tutorial. `bcdedit` is another program you might want to take a look into.

Comment: @Topdown Drive letters are not changed via the Registry _(if wanting to make changes to the Registry from WinPE/WinRE, the OS hives must be mounted first)_. In WinPE/WinRE, the OS partition is rarely `C:`, as WinPE/WinRE assigns drive letters in the order of disks and the partitions on the disks _(e.g. Disk0p1, Disk0p2, Disk1p1, Disk2 p1, etc.)_ and the OS partition will never be the first partition. Windows boot issues can always be resolved from WinRE via `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(if UEFI, only run the first and last commands)_, else `BcdBoot` can be used

Comment: Have tried:
`Bootrec /scanos` 
One installation found
`Bootrec /fixmbr`
Completed successfully
`Bootrec /fixboot`
Volume does not contain recognised filesystem
`chkdsk f: /r`
No issues to fix
`Bootrec /rebuildbcd`
Done

Still no luck booting
What now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

---

Boot recovery > advanced recovery > cmd

`Diskpart`

`list volumes` {check the letter of the drive to boot}

`exit` {to exit the dispart}

`Bcdboot D:\Windows` {replace D with the letter of the drive to boot you just checked}

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is any risk to the Bitlocker drive (which is the boot drive) using `Bcdboot`?

Comment: @Topdown no there will be no issues ; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bcd-settings-and-bitlocker#:~:text=For%20the%20purposes%20of%20BitLocker,in%20the%20Group%20Policy%20setting.

Comment: Tried this, and get unaccessible Boot Device Blue screen just as before. After booting next time I get prompted for Bitlocker key which I enter. A second after this I get a screen saying:
"Recovery"... "After multiple tries the operating system on your PC failed to start so it needs to be repaired. Error code 0xc00000001. You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disk or USB) contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer)." 
Prior to running `BCDBOOT` it would at least get me to cmd prompt. Any ideas now?I am unsure I have a recovery disk

Comment: @Topdown it seems the win drive is corrupted; if data on drive is imp then it's better not to touch the drive and do fresh installation somewhere on other partition > copy the imp files > then try repairing this